# Real time animation of multiple markers on Map

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, google-maps, amazon-dynamodb

I am developing an Android application where I have to show live location of multiple GPS devices(let's say mobile phones) on Google maps. I am using Amazon Dynamo DB as database for this application. I have successfully built an interface where Drivers can login and their live location will be stored in my database i.e Dynamo Db.

Now, problem is with the showing the markers and animating them on map. I have the following code where I am fetching all the locations stored in Dynamo DB through SCAN operation & trying to show the markers.

```
`public void showMarker(){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            int width = 50;
            int height = 50;
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.car);
            Bitmap b =bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
            Bitmap smallMarker = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b,width,height,false);
            double fetchedLatitude;
            double fetchedLongitude;
            int fetchedVehicleId;
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final Gson gson = new Gson();
                final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                final PaginatedList<VehicleLocationsDO> onTrackVehicles = dynamoDBMapper.scan(VehicleLocationsDO.class, new DynamoDBScanExpression());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                    try{
                        for (int i=0;i<onTrackVehicles.size();i++){
                            String OnTrackVehiclesString = gson.toJson(onTrackVehicles.get(i));
                            Log.e("Json String", OnTrackVehiclesString);
                            stringBuilder.append(OnTrackVehiclesString+"\n");
                            JsonModel onTrackVehiclesObject = gson.fromJson(OnTrackVehiclesString,JsonModel.class);
                            fetchedLatitude = onTrackVehiclesObject.get_latitude();
                            fetchedLongitude= onTrackVehiclesObject.get_longitude();
                            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(fetchedLatitude,fetchedLongitude);
                            if(marker == null){
                                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)) );
                                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(fetchedLatitude, fetchedLongitude), 16.5f));
                            }
                            else{
                                MarkerAnimation.animateMarkerToICS(marker,latLng, new LatLngInterpolator.Spherical());
//                              mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(fetchedLatitude,fetchedLongitude),16.5f));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e){
                        Log.e("Exception caught",e.toString());
                    }
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
    }`
```

After this, I am calling this method inside a timer which repeats itself after each 1 second. But the problem is that it is not animating the marker but it keeps on adding new markers one on the another.

Comment: You'll need to (a) maintain a collection of markers added (add the result of `addMarker`), (b) identify each driver/vehicle in some way (from your DB results) and (c) remove the previous marker for each driver/vehicle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, finally I got a solution for this as @Andy said I maintained a collection for the markers & modified the code as follows:

**1. Create a list of Markers**

```
List<Marker> markerList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
```

**2. Obtain a list of all the markers from the database**

```
 public void initialListCreation() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        int width = 50;
        int height = 50;
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.car);
        Bitmap b = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
        Bitmap smallMarker = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width, height, false);

        @Override
        public void run() {
            final Gson gson = new Gson();
            final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            final PaginatedList<VehicleLocationsDO> onTrackVehicles = dynamoDBMapper.scan(VehicleLocationsDO.class, new DynamoDBScanExpression());
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        for (int i = 0; i < onTrackVehicles.size(); i++) {
                            String OnTrackVehiclesString = gson.toJson(onTrackVehicles.get(i));
                            stringBuilder.append(OnTrackVehiclesString + "\n");
                            JsonModel onTrackVehiclesObject = gson.fromJson(OnTrackVehiclesString, JsonModel.class);
                            int fetchedVehicleId = onTrackVehiclesObject.get_vehicleId();
                            double fetchedLatitude = onTrackVehiclesObject.get_latitude();
                            double fetchedLongitude = onTrackVehiclesObject.get_longitude();
                            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(fetchedLatitude, fetchedLongitude);
                            marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                    .anchor(.5f,.5f)
                                    .position(latLng)
                                    .title("Vehicle No. "
                                    +String.valueOf(fetchedVehicleId))
                                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
                            marker.setTag(fetchedVehicleId);
                            markerList.add(marker);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}
```

**3. Then create a method to show markers and animate them as follows:**

```
public void showMarker() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        int width = 50;
        int height = 50;
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.car);
        Bitmap b = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
        Bitmap smallMarker = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width, height, false);

        @Override
        public void run() {
            final Gson gson = new Gson();
            final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            final PaginatedList<VehicleLocationsDO> onTrackVehicles = dynamoDBMapper.scan(VehicleLocationsDO.class, new DynamoDBScanExpression());
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        if (onTrackVehicles.isEmpty())
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Vehicle on Track at present", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        else {
                            for (int i = 0; i < onTrackVehicles.size(); i++) {
                                LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
                                for (Marker m : markerList) {
                                    builder.include(m.getPosition());
                                }
                                LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
                                int padding = 70; // offset from edges of the map in pixels
                                CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
                                mMap.animateCamera(cu);
                                if (markerList.isEmpty()) {
                                    String OnTrackVehiclesString = gson.toJson(onTrackVehicles.get(i));
                                    stringBuilder.append(OnTrackVehiclesString + "\n");
                                    JsonModel onTrackVehiclesObject = gson.fromJson(OnTrackVehiclesString, JsonModel.class);
                                    int fetchedVehicleId = onTrackVehiclesObject.get_vehicleId();
                                    double fetchedLatitude = onTrackVehiclesObject.get_latitude();
                                    double fetchedLongitude = onTrackVehiclesObject.get_longitude();
                                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(fetchedLatitude, fetchedLongitude);
                                    marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                            .anchor(.5f,.5f)
                                            .position(latLng)
                                            .title("Vehicle No. "
                                            + String.valueOf(fetchedVehicleId))
                                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                            .fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
                                    marker.setTag(fetchedVehicleId);
                                    markerList.add(marker);
                                } else {
                                    for (final Marker m : markerList) {
                                        String OnTrackVehiclesString = gson.toJson(onTrackVehicles.get(i));
                                        stringBuilder.append(OnTrackVehiclesString + "\n");
                                        JsonModel onTrackVehiclesObject = gson.fromJson(OnTrackVehiclesString, JsonModel.class);
                                        final int fetchedVehicleId = onTrackVehiclesObject.get_vehicleId();
                                        double fetchedLatitude = onTrackVehiclesObject.get_latitude();
                                        double fetchedLongitude = onTrackVehiclesObject.get_longitude();
                                        LatLng latLng2 = new LatLng(fetchedLatitude, fetchedLongitude);
                                        int markerTag = (int) m.getTag();
                                        if (m.getTag() != null) {
                                            if (markerTag == fetchedVehicleId) {
                                                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void run() {
                                                        final VehicleLocationsDO readNewLocation = dynamoDBMapper.load(VehicleLocationsDO.class, fetchedVehicleId);
                                                        final LatLng updatedLatLng = new LatLng(readNewLocation.getLatitude(), readNewLocation.getLongitude());
                                                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void run() {
                                                                double bearing = bearingBetweenLocations(m.getPosition(), updatedLatLng);
                                                                rotateMarker(m, (float) bearing);
                                                                MarkerAnimation.animateMarkerToGB(m, updatedLatLng, new LatLngInterpolator.Spherical());
                                                            }
                                                        });
                                                    }
                                                }).start();
                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                                    .position(latLng2)
                                                    .title(String.valueOf(fetchedVehicleId))
                                                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
                                            marker.setTag(fetchedVehicleId);
                                            markerList.add(marker);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("Exception caught", e.toString() + "  " + e.getMessage() + "  " + e.getCause());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}
```

**4. Final Step**
Now, you just need to call the initialListCreation() method just once in the onCreate() method & you can call showMarker() in periodic interval of 2000-3000(ms) using TimerTask.

That's all. Enjoy!!!